# Relaunch the app after phone restarts in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, restart

I want to restart my flutter application to automatically relaunch after phone is restarted.
I have done this in android native but now I want the same functionality in my flutter app and tried this method in flutter but its not working in there.Any help would be appreciated

This is my android native code for relaunch of application after mobile restart.

**In Manifest**

```
<receiver
            android:name=".BroadcastReceiver.RebootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

RebootReciever Class :

```
public class RebootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction()) ||
                Intent.ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED.equals(intent.getAction())
        ) {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, com.expo.exposports.ExpoMainActivity.class);
            mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(mainIntent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: iOS doesn't allow automatic app relaunch after the iPhone is restarted. I've never seen an app re-launches or launches when an iPhone is restarted.

Comment: I'm have developed this app for Android tv devices so it doesn't matter if IOS won't allow can you suggest me any method to do it in Android?\